# How to list objects on the same page with the same attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes, link-to

How to list on the home page only the `challenges` with the same `categorization` if a user clicks on the icon representing that `categorization`?

[image]

**view**

```
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :adventure) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :health) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :work) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :buy) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :wacky) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wine-glass", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
```

If a user clicks on an above `link_to` then that should only list challenges with that respective `categorization`.

**routes.rb**

```
get ":categorization", to: "pages#home", as: 'categorization'
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def home
 @challenges = current_user.challenges.send(params[:categorization]).order("deadline ASC")
end
```

**challenge.rb**

```
CATEGORIZATION = ['adventure', 'health', 'work', 'buy', 'wacky']
scope :adventure,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Adventure') }
scope :health,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Health') }
scope :work,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Work') }
scope :buy,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Buy') }
scope :wacky,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Wacky') }
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: `TypeError (nil is not a symbol):` @potashin for the line in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed it to be singular:

```
  scope :adventure,  -> { where(categorization: 'adventure') }
  scope :health,  -> { where(categorization: 'health') }
  scope :work,  -> { where(categorization: 'work') }
  scope :buy,  -> { where(categorization: 'buy') }
  scope :wacky,  -> { where(categorization: 'wacky') }
```

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/